# Describe the set of points $0 < |2z - 1| < 2$ on the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm never sure how to do these, minus the tedious algebra. I'm trying to see if I can develop a healthy intuition concerning problems of the kind; I'll summarize my approach here.

Let $w = 2z, z \in \mathbb{C}.$

Then, $0 < |2z - 1| < 2 \iff 0 < |w - 1| < 2$. The latter describes the interior of a circle of radius $2$ centered at $1 + 0i$ and excluding that point itself.

Making the appropriate adjustments for our substitution, we see that $\Re (z) \in (-.5, 1.5), \Im(z) \in (-\sqrt3/2, \sqrt3/2)$, and the center is given by $2z - 1 = 0 \iff z = .5 + 0i$. This describes the ellipse of minor radius $\sqrt3/2$, and major radius $1$, with the center $.5 + 0i$.

Is this correct? Also, would you recommend a better way of doing this?

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: $$0 < \lvert 2z-1\rvert < 2 \iff 0 < \left\lvert z - \tfrac{1}{2}\right\rvert < 1.$$

Comment: Oh, right. This is embarrassing.

Comment: "Making the appropriate adjustments for our substitution" It looks like you are doing something inappropriate here, as you get a wrong answer. :) If you show us what you did, we probably can point out the mistake, which might be instructive for you.

Comment: The answer should not be asymmetric, since translating from $w$ to $z$ should be a uniform scaling on the whole plane.

Comment: @JiK I see my mistake; when substituting back, I set $\Re(z) = 0$ to determine the range of $\Im(z)$, although I should've set $\Re(2z - 1) = 0$.

Comment: @BruceZheng Right, that had me confused too.